# Mounting my HDD as my C:\Users breaks my accounts?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, ssd, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mount second drive as c:/Users in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/53029/mount-second-drive-as-c-users-in-windows-7)

I just finished my first build. I'm using a 60GB SSD for my programs and operating system. My goal is to mount my 500GB HDD as c:/Users so all media and documents go straight to it.

I already tried [these instructions](https://superuser.com/a/53449/9666), but that only made me unable to log in to my user accounts...

Comment: Where did you find these instructions?

Comment: would'nt it be better in terms of performance to just put the actual documents/downloads/music folders on the 500gb disk but keep appdata etc on the ssd?

Comment: I found the instructions here.   http://superuser.com/questions/53029/mount-second-drive-as-c-users-in-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of pages I found that discuss this:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/win7-how-do-i-move-user-folder-to-a-different/565f16a5-e5ed-43c9-8422-4f56aebb296e

http://www.starkeith.net/coredump/2009/05/18/how-to-move-your-windows-user-profile-to-another-drive/

Comment: The second link is where I'd go for this - using the Sysinternals Junction command to create junction points for the folders you want to redirect (I've done this with folders such as SoftwareDistribution for the Windows updates, Anti-virus definition updates, Backup logs/databases etc).

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/8187/whats-the-best-way-to-move-c-users-to-d-users-under-vista-w7/8201#8201 ..... I found this as well (the easiest and recommended way) but it says I will still have the users folder in place. I tested it on a picture. I placed the picture on my HDD and deleted it on my SSD (Users folders). It was still on my HDD. Maybe I will do that instead of the hard and risky way. I'm definitely not a pro at all of this as it is my first build.

Comment: Link-only answers are a no-no on SU, due to future link rot. Please include pertinent information from the links in your question.